# Print out only the result set that has an "a" at the end of a certain value PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a foreach loop that iterates over objects in an array. Currently, it outputs information for every element. I need to print out data for only the objects that have an "a" at the end of their `id` property. Code is as follows:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo '<tr id="subRow">';
    echo '<td>' . $value->date . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="leftLine">' . $value->Name . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="leftLine">' . $value->dealType . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="leftLine">' . $value->id . '</td>';
    echo '<td class="leftLine">' . 'Adobe PDF' . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

So for every element of the `$obj` that contains an ID number with an "a" at the end of it, print out that entire element.

Comment: This question could use sample data, along with desired HTML output. When asking for help, always describe what you want and what you actually get, including any error messages. Note that the arrow operatior (`->`) only works on objects, not arrays, so the code, doesn't jibe with the description.

Comment: use substr() to get the last letter and check its "a"

Comment: Thanks for the tips outis. I will take appropriate steps to further explain my next question. I'm still learning. :) Indeed it is an object - thats basically what an associative array is anyhow.

Comment: @mdance: an associative array is definitely not an object. Objects have much more complex semantics. Arrays don't have methods, inheritance, or visibility modifiers for the data they aggregate, so they don't support encapsulation, nor any form of abstraction, nor does it make any sense to speak of polymorphism for associative arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`substr`](http://php.net/substr) can help with that:

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    if(substr($value->id, -1) === 'a') {
        echo '<tr id="subRow">';
        echo '<td>' . $value->date . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="leftLine">' . $value->Name . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="leftLine">' . $value->dealType . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="leftLine">' . $value->id . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="leftLine">' . 'Adobe PDF' . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: @outis: Rejection reason: radical change